# Expo-Audio is not working on iOS. Its stuck on recording button itself

Tags: audio, permissions, expo

github.com/expo/audio-recording-example

You can check it out about code.

I am using audio from expo-av.

It works fine with android devices even on emulator. On android device, it first asks for audio permission then started to record audio on click the on stop, it provides playback audio.

But testing on iOS, it does not asking for permission too, directly shows the audio recording page, and clicking on record button , recording doesn't started.

I can't understand whether its problem with iOS audio permission or syntax of audio.recording.

I've tried to set permission manually true

```
    this.recordingSettings = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_LOW_QUALITY));
    // // UNCOMMENT THIS TO TEST maxFileSize:
    // this.recordingSettings.android['maxFileSize'] = 12000;
  }

  _askForPermissions = async () => {
    const response = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING);
    this.setState({
      haveRecordingPermissions: response.status === 'granted',
    });
  };

  async _stopPlaybackAndBeginRecording() {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
    });
    if (this.sound !== null) {
      await this.sound.unloadAsync();
      this.sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(null);
      this.sound = null;
    }
    await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
      allowsRecordingIOS: true,
      interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
      playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      shouldDuckAndroid: true,
      interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
      playThroughEarpieceAndroid: false,
      staysActiveInBackground: true,
    });
    if (this.recording !== null) {
      this.recording.setOnRecordingStatusUpdate(null);
      this.recording = null;
    }

    const recording = new Audio.Recording();
    await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(this.recordingSettings);
    recording.setOnRecordingStatusUpdate(this._updateScreenForRecordingStatus);

    this.recording = recording;
    await this.recording.startAsync(); // Will call this._updateScreenForRecordingStatus to update the screen.
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
    });
  }

  _onRecordPressed = () => {
    if (this.state.isRecording) {
      this._stopRecordingAndEnablePlayback();
    } else {
      this._stopPlaybackAndBeginRecording();
    }
  };
```

I expect audio recording on iOS but gets stuck on `isrecording`.

Comment: Can you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I just change my audio settings. @GermanAlzate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my recording settings and everything is goof on both devices android and iOS.
My updated Settings.

```
    this.recordingSettings = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY: RecordingOptions = {
      android: {
        extension: '.m4a',
        outputFormat: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG_4,
        audioEncoder: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AAC,
        sampleRate: 44100,
        numberOfChannels: 2,
        bitRate: 128000,
    },
    ios: {
        extension: '.m4a',
        outputFormat: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_IOS_OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG4AAC,
        audioQuality: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_IOS_AUDIO_QUALITY_MIN,
        sampleRate: 44100,
        numberOfChannels: 2,
        bitRate: 128000,
        linearPCMBitDepth: 16,
        linearPCMIsBigEndian: false,
        linearPCMIsFloat: false,
    },
    }));
```

This used this setting according to my requirement you can used another setting options too.. But just keep Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY same.